# Subset r data.table conditionally using is.null()

Tags: r, null, data.table, subset

I have a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

testDT <- data.table(
        L = (1:32), 
        M = rep(letters[23:26], each = 64), 
        N = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 2, each = 512),
        O = rnorm(2048, 1))

testDT$L                <- factor(testDT$L,         levels = seq(from = 1, to = 32, by = 1))
```

I created a function to subset the data set conditionally. If the subsetting variable `G` is `NULL` and `H` is `"w"`, then I want all values within `testDT$N` and all values `"w"` in `testDT$M` to be returned in `testDT`. This is what I created, which does not function correctly:

```
G <- NULL 
H <- "w"

testDT1 <- testDT[if(is.null(G)) {eval(call("%in%", as.name("N"), G))} & 
                if(is.null(H)) {eval(call("%in%", as.name("M"), H))}]
```

I verified that everything but the `if(is.null())` portion works by creating this, which subsets correctly:

```
G <- "A" 
H <- "w"
testDT1 <- testDT[{eval(call("%in%", as.name("N"), G))} & 
                {eval(call("%in%", as.name("M"), H))}]
```

How can I use the `is.null()` condition correctly?

Comment: I added a additional detail to the question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am trying to do it this way because a) I'm using `shiny` and b) I have 12 columns to subset by. If I do it that way, then I need 144 (12^2) combinations, whereas if I can get this to work correctly, then it should handle it in 12 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using computing on the language you can prepare `call` object using dedicated function.

```
library(data.table)
testDT = data.table(
    L = factor(1:32), 
    M = rep(letters[23:26], each = 64), 
    N = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 2, each = 512),
    O = rnorm(2048, 1)
)

i.expr = function(var, x){
    if(is.null(x)) TRUE
    else call("%in%", as.name(var), x)
}

G = NULL
H = "w"
i.expr("N",G)
#[1] TRUE
i.expr("M",H)
#M %in% "w"
testDT1 = testDT[eval(i.expr("N",G)) & eval(i.expr("M",H))]

G = "A" 
H = "w"
i.expr("N",G)
#N %in% "A"
i.expr("M",H)
#M %in% "w"
testDT2 = testDT[eval(i.expr("N",G)) & eval(i.expr("M",H))]
```

If you always subset by two conditions and `&` operator. I would merge it into a single function so you can call it once using `testDT[eval(i.expr(...))]`.

Comment: For some reason, this is not working for me. When I execute `testDT1`, it shows a dataset with no rows.

Comment: @black_sheep07 this is correct results for your conditions, try `testDT[is.null(N) & M %in% "w"]`

Comment: When `G = NULL`, I want to return ALL values of `N`, not none of them.